# jquery autocomplete else if item is not selected

Tags: jquery

I am using this jquery autocomplete code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
          $("#contact_name").autocomplete({
              source:data,
              select: function(e, ui) {
                  e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
                  $("#contact_email").val(ui.item.value);
                  $(this).val(ui.item.label);

                  $("#AddAsContact").css('display', 'none');
                  $('#AddAsContact').prop('checked', false);
              }
          });
      });
```

its working great, exactly as it should but if an item from the auto complete list is not selected and something else is just typed into the text input, how can i run some different code. Kind of like `else { ...code here... }`

Answer (score 10):

`select` event is triggered when you `select` something from the DropDown.

You can use the `change` event for determining whether the item falls under the autocomplete list or not,

```
 change: function (event, ui) {
         if (ui.item === null) {
              $(this).val('');
              $('#field_id').val('');
         }
       }
```

And, here is a [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/170/) for you.

Hope this help you.

Comment: thank you - this doesnt seem to allow my code to work properly, its not putting the correct information in each box. http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/171/

Comment: So, What exactly do you want to perform here ... if no value is selected from the DropDown?

Comment: i want my code to work exactly as it does now putting the value and label into the 2 text inputs when an item from the autocomplete list is selected but if no item is selected and values are just typed into the two text boxes then i want to do some other code